# R: How to setNames to list objects and sub-objects

Tags: r, list, naming

Consider this list with sublists:

```
my_sub_list <- list()
my_sub_list[[1]] <- lst(mtcars[1:10,])
my_sub_list[[2]] <- lst(mtcars[11:20,])

my_list[[1]] <- my_sub_list
my_list[[2]] <- my_sub_list
my_list[[3]] <- my_sub_list
```

I want to rename the `[[1]]`, `[[2]]` and `[[3]]` components and have labels instead of numbers.
How to do this?

This does not work to rename the first level objects.

```
setNames(my_list, c('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))
```

[image]

Ideally I would end up with labels for all objects:

```
my_list
   [[label1]]
          [[label1.1]]
          [[label1.2]]
   [[label2]]
          [[label2.1]]
          [[label2.2]]
   [[label3]]
          [[label3.1]]
          [[label3.2]]
```

Comment: What package are you getting `lst` from? Your example is not really working for me, so I suspect there is an issue in how you are creating the lists and what packages you have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having a think about how to get the label as a prefix for the sub label but this will get you going in the meantime.

```
my_list <- setNames(lapply(my_list, setNames, paste0('sub_label', 1:2)), paste0('label', 1:3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the library `purrr`, you can iterate over each sublist and name accordingly.

```r
library(purrr)

my_list <- set_names(my_list, c('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))
imap(my_list, ~ set_names(.x, paste(.y, seq_along(.x), sep = ".")))
```

If you wanted to stay in base, you could use `Map` instead.

```r
my_list <- setNames(my_list, c('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))
Map(function(.x, .y) setNames(.x, paste(.y, seq_along(.x), sep = ".")), my_list, names(my_list))
```

---

**Data**

I was not having luck with your example, so I changed the code to this which seemed to match your output better. Maybe that was also part of the issue.

```r
my_sub_list <- my_list <- list()
my_sub_list[[1]] <- mtcars[1:10,]
my_sub_list[[2]] <- mtcars[11:20,]

my_list[[1]] <- my_sub_list
my_list[[2]] <- my_sub_list
my_list[[3]] <- my_sub_list
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this working better?

```
my_list = setNames(my_list, c('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))
```